# php turn array in to mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a form which is submitted, where a user is created and can be assigned a number of roles:
for example (Admin, User etc.)

The form posts the data as an array `roles[]`.

When only one role was selectable I had one `mysqli_query()` create the user (in the users table). Then the second create a row in the roleid table which matched up a userid with a roleid using mysqls `LAST_INSERT_ID`, will the mysql `LAST_INSERT_ID` work if there is more than one role assigned to the user?

The three tables are as follows:

```
users (name, email, password, id)
roleid (userid, roleid)
roles(id, description)
```

I need to create an entry in the roleid table for each checkbox that is selected by the user creation form. I thought about imploding the array (`implode(',',$roles)`) but im not sure mysql accepts values in that form. Any ideas?

Comment: Save the `LAST_INSERT_ID` in a PHP variable.  Then use the variable in your queries.

Comment: You can do `INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)`.

Comment: ok so ive got php to construct the sql statement as `INSERT INTO roleid (userid, roleid) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'1') (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'2')` will `LAST_INSERT_ID()` work if its called twice in the same statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to either query once per role, or insert multiple records in one query. With MySQLi you could even use prepared statements for this.

```
$user_id = mysqli_insert_id();
$query = "INSERT INTO `roleid` (userid, roleid) VALUES ";

foreach($roles as $index => $role_id) {
  $roles[$index] = "($user_id," . intval($role_id) . ")";
}

$query .= implode(', ', $roles);
```

Answer (score 1):

If You once insert a user into the `users` table and save that `LAST_INSERT_ID` into a variable, e.g. `$last_insert_id` You can then perform as many queries using this `$last_insert_id` as You want (while it is not overwrited :-) ).

So:

1. insert new user
2. retrieve `$last_insert_id`
3. for each role ID run `insert into roleid values ($role_id, $last_insert_id)`
   OR
   run one `insert into roleid values ($role_id_1, $last_insert_id), ($role_id_2, $last_insert_id), ($role_id_3, $last_insert_id), ...`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (count($roles)) {
   $qry="INSERT INTO roleid (userid, roleid) VALUES ";
   $part="($user_insert_id, ";
   $qry . = $part . implode(")," . $part, roles) . ")";
   mysql_query($ary, $db_handle);
}
```